# What is the future of CAPTCHA?

Tags: captcha

According to [this article](http://www.mperfect.net/aiCaptcha/)  this guy has made a simple AI to beat CAPTCHA. With the development of AI, robots will pass the Turing test, and bots will beat Google's reCAPTCHA, maybe already there are robots that can beat all captchas, so, what will be the future of captcha? Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be highly opinion based. There are several posts online that provide different human detection solutions and options. [Here](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Captcha_Alternatives_and_thoughts)'s a discussion on W3 that discusses the problems and alternatives.

Comment: The 'future' will depend on future development and the value people assign to the technology.

Comment: ... the only date I see on that page is of **2005**. So it is completely obsolete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> According to this article this guy has made a simple ai to beat CAPTCHA.

Those are old CAPTCHA algorithms. Newer ones are harder.

> With the development of AI, robots will pass the Turing test

That's pure speculation. Personally, I don't think we're even close.

> maybe already there are robots that can beat all captchas

Except there aren't.

> what will be the future of captcha?

Let's assume that computers will be able to pass the Turing test at some indeterminate time in the future. At that time, a computer will also be able to tell spam apart from quality content, as humans can. This obviates the *need* for CAPTCHAs.

Answer (score 3):

Even some of the new algorithms are broken as well as per this paper. https://cdn.elie.net/publications/text-based-captcha-strengths-and-weaknesses.pdf

Many marketing companies employ cheap labor for breaking captchas, so it is breakable as of today also.

So, accepted that they can be broken but for what cost is the point to evaluate ? If your data is worth millions they somebody may employ human labor to break it. Check "Podec", it was a trojan that forwards CAPTCHA requests to an online human translation service. So you may consider other costly approaches like setting SOC\NOC center.

There are different kind of implementations being used like Animal Species Image Recognition for Restricting Access (ASIRRA) is asking users to identify cats from dogs and that seems pretty difficult. Text based captchas were vulnerable to OCR which has been evolved over years (10+) as a part of natural language processing.

Non text based captchas will be there for another 10-15 yrs if not less.